# Reverse Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations

I have a parent object, Post, which has the following children.

```
has_one :link
has_one :picture
has_one :code
```

These children are mutually exclusive.

Is there a way to use polymorphic associations in reverse so that I don't have to have link_id, picture_id, and code_id fields in my Post table?

Comment: Would it make sense to have the photo have a :has_many relationship?

Then you could do what you're looking for..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote up a small Gist showing how to do this:
https://gist.github.com/1242485

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `:as` option for `has_one`. It allows you to specify the name of the `belongs_to` association end.

When all else fails, read the docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how would I create a dynamic association with a child using :as?

I understand polymorphism in regards to how a child object could have any type of parent object.  But what I am asking is how a parent object can have any type of child object.

I want to do something like @post.postable and get the child object, which would be one of link, picture, or code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use polymorphic
>   associations in reverse so that I
>   don't have to have link_id,
>   picture_id, and code_id fields in my
>   Post table?

`has_one` implies that the foreign key is in the *other* table. If you've really defined your model this way, then you won't have `link_id`, `picture_id`, and `code_id` in your Post table. I think you meant to say `belongs_to`.

> I want to do something like
>   @post.postable and get the child
>   object, which would be one of link,
>   picture, or code.

I believe you could do this by using STI and combining the `links`, `pictures`, and `codes` tables, then testing the type of the model when retrieving. That seems kludgey though, and could end up with lots of unused columns.

Is there a reason for not storing the unused id columns, other than saving space? If you're willing to keep them, then you could define a virtual attribute and a `postable_type` column : *(untested code, may fail spectacularly)*

```
def postable
  self.send(self.postable_type)
end

def postable=(p)
  self.send(postable_type.to_s+"=",p)
end
```

Comment: I'm just searching for a more elegant way of doing things than having multiple *_id columns. Though as this thread is proving out, the multiple *_id columns approach is probably the simplest and the best.