# has_many through multiple models with a unique source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

To take an example everyone is familiar with, think of StackOverflow.
A user `has_many :questions`, `has_many :answers` and her questions and answers may be commented. (Comment is polymorphic).

I want to get all the responses addressed to a particular user via a comment on either this user's questions or answers:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :responses, through: [:questions, :answers], source: :comments
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Of course, `has_many :responses, through: [:questions, :answers], source: :comments` doesn't work.

Is there a Rails way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487730/reverse-polymorphic-associations

Comment: @DGM Thanks but sadly not. By the way, the accepted answer is really not the right thing to do IMO.

Comment: how about write conditions sql in assocation?

Comment: I found an alternative trick  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193615/rails-has-many-through-for-has-many-with-multiple-models)

Comment: @Damien hello just wondering whether you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
has_many :responses, :class_name => "Comment", :finder_sql =>
          'SELECT DISTINCT comments.* ' +
          'FROM comments c, questions q, answers a ' +
          'WHERE (c.commentable_id = a.id and c.commentable_type='Answer' and a.user_id = #{id} ) or (c.commentable_id = q.id and c.commentable_type='Question' and q.user_id = #{id})'
```