# Rails has_many through for has_many with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, relational-database, has-many

What would be the best way to model the following situation:

```
Word
  belongs_to :wordable, :polymorphic => true


Phrase
  has_many :words, :as => :workable
  belongs_to :story

Line
  has_many :words, :as => :wordable    
  belongs_to :story


Story
 has_many :lines      
 has_many :phrases
 has_many :words, :through => :phrases
 has_many :words, :through => :lines
```

I want to be able to do

```
 @story.words
```

to get list of all words that are linked to a story either via lines or via phrases...

Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Story

  has_many :lines      
  has_many :phrases

  def words(reload=false)
    @words = nil if reload
    @words ||= Word.where("(wordable_type = ? AND wordable_id IN (?)) OR
                            (wordable_type = ? AND wordable_id IN (?))", 
                           "Phrase", phrase_ids, "Line", line_ids)    
  end
end
```

Now

```
story.words # returns line and phrase words
story.words.limit(5)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. Could you please explain what the `= nil if reload` is for? Thanks much.

Comment: The `Story` object caches the results in an instance variable called `@words`. Under certain scenarios you might want to bust the cache. You can do so by passing `true` value for the `reload` parameter.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. I see it could be good to have this option to access from the console or a rake task if the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the 2 `has_many :words, :through => XXX` relations from the `Story` class, and define a method `words` instead :

```
def words 
  ([] << lines.collect {|line| line.words} << phrases.collect {|phrase| phrase.words}).flatten
end
```

Comment: Thank you, switching from polymorphic to  a relation via phrase_id and line_id in Word model is a bad idea?

Comment: With the polymorphic relation, you will be able to add a new `Wordable` more easily. With your second suggestion, you'll need a migration to add a column for each new `Wordable`

Comment: thanks, since you were the first, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: @stpn, You will not be able to chain the sql and paginate the result-set when you append the lists in Ruby (rather than SQL).

Comment: @stpn The solution of KandadaBoggu is better.

Comment: ok  guess I will read more about it.. accepting KandadaBoggu's answer now thanks a lot.