# Has many polymorphic resources (with ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, polymorphism

Let's say we use ActiveRecord and there's a user (`User` model) having many comments (`Comment` model) and many articles (`Article` model).  We can write this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

...so I can do `user.comments` and `user.articles`:

```
user.comments # => [#<Comment:0x12bfcd010>, #<Comment:0x3928c1101>]
user.articles # => [#<Article:0x10aacd333>]
```

Considering Article and Comment as an item, is that possible to do so (with 1 query)?

```
user.items # => [#<Comment:0x12bfcd010>, #<Article:0x10aacd333>, #<Comment:0x3928c1101>]
```

...This way, an item could looks like a polymorphcal attached resource.  Even if it's not a normal [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

I think this would be possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked before, best to google for reverse polymorphic associations. That said, here's the question asking the same thing.

[Reverse Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487730/reverse-polymorphic-associations)

And the answer then links to this gist, which illustrates a way to do it pretty well.

https://gist.github.com/1242485