# Reverse Polymorphic Association in Rails (Accessing the parent's attributes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I implemented an example of Reverse Polymorphism in Rails with the selected answer from this question:
[Reverse Polymorphic Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487730/reverse-polymorphic-associations)

With this we are able to do the following:

```
t = Article.new
t.article_elements  # []
p = Picture.new
t.article_elements.create(:element => p)
t.article_elements  # [<ArticleElement id: 1, article_id: 1, element_id: 1, element_type: "Picture", created_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45", updated_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45">]
t.pictures # [#<Picture id: 1, created_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45", updated_at: "2011-09-26 18:26:45">]
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to modify this such that if I do 
`t.article_elements` that I can also see the attributes for the picture to. So for example, if I had an picture_name attribute for the variable p, how can I access that from t.article_elements ? So basically, I am trying to access the parent's attributes from the child object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that `t.article_elements` is a collection. I will use `article_element` to refer to one member of the collection.*

Per your example,

```
article_element.element.picture_name
```

will work.

However, you run into a problem with undefined methods by mismatched attributes. For example, a video would not have a `picture_name` attribute. If all element types shared a common attribute, such as `name`, it would be fine.

One way to avoid this problem is to check whether the element responds to a given attribute method. For example:

```
# models/article_element.rb
def element_try(method)
  self.element.respond_to?(method) ? self.element.send(method) : ""
end
```

If our element is a video and we call:

```
article_element.element_try(:picture_name) # => ""
```

we will get a blank string instead of `NoMethodError`.

This solution is a bit hacky, so use at your own risk. Personally, I'd use common attributes instead.

Comment: thanks for this answer.  i suppose this could work. I also figured that you could do                                      t.article_elements.map {|x| x.element} # this iterates through each article_element and returns its associated parent model and all its attributes

Comment: Another solution to the problem of specific names would be to use something like this: article_element.element.send("#{element_type}_name"). But ofc. only if the name varied with the type name.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar situation.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image, as: :imageable
end
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image, as: :imageable
end
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

When you wanna access parent of image, you can do `Image.last.imageable` and that will give you either User or Person object. It works same with has_many relations.